# Structuring a website's pages

Tags: php, architecture

I am new to the web development scene and recently I have started to wonder as what constitutes as a solid structure for organizing my web pages. I had picked up something that I felt was working for me but after consulting a friend we both ended up on different sides of an argument. I'm hoping I am not asking a question that deems opinion but rather I hope I can get a straight forward answer.

The original way my files were organized is as so:

```
-- website
----- Index.php
----- projects
------------ index.php
------ about
------------ index.php
----- contact
------------ index.php
------ lib
------------ img
------------ js
------------ php
------------ css
```

The way I was told to structure:

```
-- website
----- index.php
----- about.php
----- contact.php
----- projects
------------ index.php
------ lib
------------ img
------------ js
------------ php
------------ css
```

If someone could give me pointers as to why any is better or worse, that would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this website for you, open source or going to be on the market?
In my honest opinion the best file structure is what you are comfy with and can find what you are looking for painlessly. If you are planning to make this available to the public either free or paid you can still find the previous usefull. But if I had to choose between your 2 examples I like the first one since for me looking at folders looks better than a bunch of files.

If you do break it up by files you can in a way make it a bit more "modular" for lack of a better term and include particular assets to the page like its own stylesheet, images, etc

Comment: The website is in fact for my personal use, but the reason I have asked this question is for example, I do end up working collaboratively on a website, I just want to make sure my structure I am comfortable with does not deviate too much from the norm.

Comment: Well I would say there really is no "norm" and if you are working with a team ask them since they are the ones that will have to deal with it as well.